# IdentityServer4 design of the PersistedGrants table

Tags: identityserver4

PersistedGrants table has ClientId, SubjectId and Type columns as navchars. I would expect them to be foreign keys instead referencing to Clients, Subjects and Type tables. I've been wandering why this patter has been chosen? Is it performing better this way despite taking more space?
Also keeping all in one thread, how can I configure IdentityServer4 to delete expired rows(Keys)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not the author but I'd imagine it's because the design of the framework is not wedded to having to use a relational DB. The repositories for configuration and operational data are separate and could live in physically separate databases and therefore enforcing referential integrity when you happen to be using the same DB for both doesn't really make sense.